# To read RTF files, is there a package, besides libreoffice, I can install on RHEL7?

Tags: rhel, yum, libreoffice

I received an `rtf` formatted file on an RHEL7 machine - that does not have libreoffice.
Is there a package I can (`yum`) `install` - that will allow me to read that rtf file?

Comment: Related: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/64018/117549

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/312348/117549

Answer (score 0):

A poor substitute, particularly with graphical content, but a starting point:

```
strings Document.rtf
```

Answer (score 0):

Abiword can edit rtf, you can find it here https://sourceforge.net/projects/abiword/?source=directory, but it's in the repositories too.